# Why can I pull images from a private repo but not create a kubernetes deployment with it?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I have a container image (let's call it FOO in this example) in a private docker hub repository that, after authenticating with 'docker login', i'm easily able to pull by calling

```
docker pull myusername/FOO:1.0
```

I can pull it, run it locally - works great.

However, when I try to launch a deployment with that image via -

```
kubectl create deployment footest --image=myusername/FOO:1.0
```

it fails to pull the image. When I set the image to public, everything works fine though. It's when it's in private mode I can't create a Kubernetes deployment with it.

Any indication on what next steps I should do here to be able to pull this private image?

Comment: to pull image you have to add secret which will be storing authentication credentials to pull images from private repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a secret which will be storing repo authentication details.

you have to update deployment with

```
imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistrykey
```

for more details you can have a look at official document :https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

example :

create pod using private repo image

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

you can create sceret using

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

where:

```
<your-registry-server> is your Private Registry.
<your-name> is your Docker username.
<your-pword> is your Docker password.
<your-email> is your Docker email.
```